# Filesystem is reporting a write error on a specific sector even after the partition is moved further

Tags: linux, btrfs, badblocks

I am facing the following problem: btrfs reports write errors for sector 128 on device `/dev/sdd`:

```
sd 6:0:0:0: [sdd] Invalid command failure
sd 6:0:0:0: [sdd] Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
sd 6:0:0:0: [sdd] Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
sd 6:0:0:0: [sdd] Add. Sense: Invalid field in cdb
sd 6:0:0:0: [sdd] CDB: Write(10): 2a 08 00 00 00 80 00 00 08 00
end_request: critical target error, dev sdd, sector 128
BTRFS: lost page write due to I/O error on /dev/sdd
BTRFS: bdev /dev/sdd errs: wr 913238, rd 1, flush 150, corrupt 0, gen 0
```

I have run `badblocks /dev/sdd` and it returned no badblocks. Anyway, I decided to stay on safe side (in a way), created a partition that starts at sector 2048 (default):

```
# fdisk -l /dev/sdd
Device     Boot Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdd1        2048 234441647 234439600 111.8G 83 Linux
```

and re-added the drive to btrfs volume. Instantly I got the same write error again (note that 2176 = 2048 + 128):

```
sd 13:0:0:0: [sdd] Invalid command failure
sd 13:0:0:0: [sdd] Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
sd 13:0:0:0: [sdd] Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
sd 13:0:0:0: [sdd] Add. Sense: Invalid field in cdb
sd 13:0:0:0: [sdd] CDB: Write(10): 2a 08 00 00 08 80 00 00 08 00
end_request: critical target error, dev sdd, sector 2176
BTRFS: lost page write due to I/O error on /dev/sdd1
BTRFS: bdev /dev/sdd1 errs: wr 12253, rd 0, flush 0, corrupt 0, gen 0
```

Could it be that both sectors 128 and 2176 are bad? Well, I have re-run `badblocks /dev/sdd` (again, it has reported no bad blocks), and pushed the partition further away:

```
# fdisk -l /dev/sdd
Device     Boot Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdd1        4096 234441647 234437552 111.8G 83 Linux
```

and re-created btrfs volume. Again "bad block" at the same magic place (4224 = 4096 + 128):

```
sd 6:0:0:0: [sdd] Invalid command failure
sd 6:0:0:0: [sdd] Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
sd 6:0:0:0: [sdd] Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
sd 6:0:0:0: [sdd] Add. Sense: Invalid field in cdb
sd 6:0:0:0: [sdd] CDB: Write(10): 2a 08 00 00 10 80 00 00 08 00
end_request: critical target error, dev sdd, sector 4224
BTRFS: lost page write due to I/O error on /dev/sdd1
BTRFS: bdev /dev/sdd1 errs: wr 124433, rd 0, flush 0, corrupt 0, gen 0
```

I don't believe in co-incidences, namely, that no other sector before magic 128 and after 128 are failing, but that specific one is problematic.

What is can be? For me sounds like a bug in kernel.

Additional info:

- Linux kernel v3.16.0
- `/dev/sdd` is connected via SATA-to-USB adapter JMicron (ID 152d:0567, [see how it looks like](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Slim-USB-3-0-to-22-Pin-SATA-2-5-SSD-Hard-Disk-Drive-Adapter-Cable-3Gbps-AirShip-/271564952557)):

dmesg:

```
sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
scsi 6:0:0:0: Direct-Access     JMicron  Generic          0116 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
sd 6:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg5 type 0
sd 6:0:0:0: [sdd] 234441648 512-byte logical blocks: (120 GB/111 GiB)
sd 6:0:0:0: [sdd] Write Protect is off
sd 6:0:0:0: [sdd] Mode Sense: 47 00 10 08
sd 6:0:0:0: [sdd] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, supports DPO and FUA
sd 6:0:0:0: [sdd] Attached SCSI disk
```

Comment: I suspect the problem is not a bad block at all, but a controller or driver bug, possibly one that's triggered by a certain access pattern that btrfs happens to make.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like I have found the root of the problem. It is really connected with JMicron SATA bridge, see [External USB3 disk fails with "Invalid field in cdb"](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.linux.scsi/91894). [The fix](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.linux.usb.general/119973) with [commit bf5c4136fa5ce471bdbf4cf59a813e32755fd014](https://kernel.googlesource.com/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable/+/bf5c4136fa5ce471bdbf4cf59a813e32755fd014) is included into [kernel v3.18.6](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v3.x/ChangeLog-3.18.6), released on 2015-02-06. I have tried the following kernels:

- [3.18.6-1~exp1](http://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/20150208T160746Z/pool/main/l/linux/linux-image-3.18.0-trunk-686-pae_3.18.6-1%7Eexp1_i386.deb) – didn't work
- [3.19.3-1~exp1](http://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/20150330T214308Z/pool/main/l/linux/linux-image-3.19.0-trunk-686-pae_3.19.3-1%7Eexp1_i386.deb) – didn't work
- [4.2.3-2~bpo8+1](http://ftp.nl.debian.org/debian/pool/main/l/linux/linux-image-4.2.0-0.bpo.1-686-pae_4.2.3-2~bpo8+1_i386.deb) – didn't work.

The actual fix was committed as [9fa62b1a31c96715aef34f25000e882ed4ac4876](https://kernel.googlesource.com/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable/+/9fa62b1a31c96715aef34f25000e882ed4ac4876%5E!/) and available in kernel 4.4.x.

dmesg for working kernel v4.4.x is the following:

```
scsi host7: uas
scsi 7:0:0:0: Direct-Access     JMicron  Generic          0116 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] 234441648 512-byte logical blocks: (120 GB/111 GiB)
sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] 4096-byte physical blocks
sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 53 00 10 08
sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] Disabling FUA
sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
```